# Delay in youtube PubSubHubbub notifications

Tags: push-notification, youtube, youtube-api, atom-feed, websub

I have subscribed my server to my Youtube channel via youtube
PubSubHubbub. I am experiencing delay in notifications sometimes.

***Is there anyway ( like statistics, tracking, youtube API ) by which I can know, when the PubSubHubbub event is fired, so that I can actually know, if there is a delay?***.

The atom feed looks like this:

```
<entry> 
 <id>yt:video:vidxxx</id> 
 <yt:videoId>videxxx</yt:videoId> 
 <yt:channelId>channelxxx</yt:channelId> 
 <title> titlexxx</title> 
 <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vidxxx"/> 
 <author> <name>Author</name> 
  <uri> https://www.youtube.com/channel/channelxxx </uri> 
 </author> 
 <published>2019-01-06T13:00:57+00:00</published> 
 <updated>2019-01-06T17:18:07+00:00</updated> 
<media:group> <media:title> title xxx </media:title> 
 <media:content url="https://www.youtube.com/v/xxx?version=3" 
  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="390"/> 
 <media:thumbnail url="https://i2.ytimg.com/vi/xxx/hqdefault.jpg" 
  width="480" height="360"/> 
 <media:description> description XXX </media:description> 
 <media:community> 
  <media:starRating count="45" average="4.91" min="1" max="5"/> 
  <media:statistics views="70593"/> 
 </media:community> 
 </media:group> 
</entry>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Define delay. How much delay are you experiencing?

Comment: Also, unless I'm not understanding, by definition, when you receive a notification at your server is— ah, nevermind this comment.. I suppose your curious whether it's the hub that is late to get notified or if the hub is just late to forward that to you.

Comment: @naki yeah you got me right! I have no way to know... if it's the hub that is late to get notified or if the hub is just late to forward that to me. I experience delay up to 1 day :(